# /etc/paths vs $PATH

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Why do I see less output when I use the following?

`sudo nano /etc/paths`

Output:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin
```

than with...

`tr ':' '\n' <<<$PATH`

Output:

```
/opt/homebrew/bin
/opt/homebrew/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin
```

With that I mean that I see fewer paths in the first option.

I was expecting the same output.

Comment: `/etc/path` is used to *initalize* `PATH`; additional directories like `/opt/homebrew/bin` are added later in the shell configuration process.

Comment: See the Unix & Linux question ["What is the difference between "echo $PATH" and /etc/paths?"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356688/what-is-the-difference-between-echo-path-and-etc-paths)

Answer (score 2):

`zsh` sources `/etc/profile` early in the process of starting a login shell, and one thing this file does is evaluate the output of `/usr/libexec/path_helper` in order to initialize the value of `PATH` in the environment.

One way `path_helper` finds directories to add to `PATH` is to read `/etc/paths`. Once `PATH` is defined, other code in additional configuration files can add directories (like `/opt/homebrew/bin`) to `PATH` as well.